# Recursively get all the vertices emerging from a group of vertices

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I have a vertex label "group" and a group can have multiple "categories".
For example, a group named "food" can have multiple categories like "Seafood, Chinese, Indian" which are connected by an edge labelled "label1". 
Now, a category can have further categories, like "Seafood" can have "fish, prawns" and so on. the depth is arbitrary and these all further categories are connected by edge labelled "label2".

```
food --label1--> seafood --label2--> fish --label2--> jellyfish --label2--> so on
                                          --label2--> starfish
                         --label2--> prawns
                         --label2--> crab

     --label1--> Indian  
     --label1--> Chinese
```

I want to recursively traverse all the vertices and get the data.
I hope you understood the question. Please help me out.

Comment: also please suggest if there is any other better way to store such data, like a menu and further sub-menus and so on.

Answer (score 2):

It's as easy as:

```
g.V(food).out("label1").
  emit().
    repeat(out("label2"))
```

Comment: yes that gives me all the vertices :).  But that doesn't give me parent child info. Can I get it in a tree structure? So that I have a heirarchical structure.

Comment: please help me in this

Comment: Append a `.tree()` step and perhaps read the docs. You're asking for pretty basic things.